# memorylessness of geometric distribution

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, stopping-times

We are given random variables  $X_k=I_k \cdot B_k$, where $I_k$ is Bernoulli with parameter $p$  and $B_k$ geometric with parameter $q$. So it holds: $$P(X_k=i)= p \cdot (1-q)^{i-1} \cdot q $$

Consider: $$Y_k =c+k-\sum_{j=1}^k X_k$$ and the stopping time: $$\tau=\inf\{ n\geq 1: Y_n \leq 0\} $$ for $k \in \mathbb{N}$ and $c\geq 1$

I want to prove: $$P(\tau=k, -Y_\tau=j)=P(\tau=k) \cdot (1-q)^j q$$

My approach: Rewrite

$$P( -Y_{\tau}=j \mid \tau=k) \cdot P(\tau=k) =\\
P( -Y_k=j) \cdot P(\tau=k)$$

Consider the first factor: The definition of $\tau$ tells us that:

$$Y_{k-1}>0$$  and therefore $$X_k > Y_{k-1}>0$$

This implies:

$$P(-Y_{k-1} + X_k-1=j \mid X_k > Y_{k-1}>0) \\= P(X_k =1+j+Y_{k-1}\mid X_k > Y_{k-1}>0, X_k>0) \\=P(X_k=j+1, X_k>0) =  (1-q)^j q$$

Can I argue like that?

Edit:
$$P( -Y_{k}=j \mid \tau=k) \overset{!}{=}P ( -Y_{k}=j )$$
The events are not independent, but if I plug in $\tau=k$, the event $\{\tau=k\}$ would not give further information?

Comment: You have $\Pr(B_k=i) = q(1-q)^{i-1}$ for $i=1,2,3,\ldots$ so $\Pr(B_k=i) = pq(1-q)^{i-1}$ for $i=1,2,3,\ldots,$ but also $\Pr(B_k=i) = 1-p$ if $i=0.\qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy: Is my result right in the end?

Comment: $P(-Y_\tau=j|\tau=k)=P(-Y_k=j)$ does not hold. It is true that $P(-Y_\tau=j|\tau=k)=P(-Y_k=j|\tau=k)$, but that does not allow you to remove the condition, since the events $\{-Y_k=j\}$ and $\{\tau=k\}$ are not independent.

Comment: Is $j$ a positive integer or just any integer?

Comment: @MatheMartin: Yes it is a positive integer.  How can I argue then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the proof: Allthough not directly stated, I am going to assume $j\in\mathbb{N}$. First of all, as you have correctly followed: $$\textbf{P}(-Y_\tau=j,\tau=k)=\textbf{P}(-Y_k=j,\tau=k)$$ Now we proof the claim by induction over $k\in\mathbb{N}$

Let $k=1$. In this case, $$\textbf{P}(-Y_k=j,\tau=k)=\textbf{P}(Y_1=-j,\tau=1)=\textbf{P}(Y_1=-j),$$ since $Y_1=-j$ implies $\tau=1$. Since \begin{align*}\textbf{P}(\tau=1)&=\textbf{P}(Y_1\leq0)=\textbf{P}(c+1-X_1\leq0)=\textbf{P}(X_1\geq c+1)\\&=1-\textbf{P}(X_1\leq c)=1-\sum^c_{i=0}\textbf{P}(X_1=i)\\&=1-(1-p)-\sum^c_{i=1}\textbf{P}(X_1=i)\\&=p-pq(1-(1-q)^c)/(1-(1-q))=p(1-q)^c\end{align*} and \begin{align*}\textbf{P}(Y_1=-j)=\textbf{P}(c+1-X_1=-j)=\textbf{P}(X_1=c+1+j)=pq(1-q)^{c+j},\end{align*} the claim follows for $k=1$.

We are trying to prove that $k\Rightarrow k+1$. Since the structure of random walks is inherently recursive, conditioning on the first step should work (let the index of the probability measure denote the start of the random walk):

\begin{align*}\textbf{P}_c(\tau=k+1)&=\sum^{c}_{i=0}\textbf{P}_c(\tau=k+1|X_1=i)\textbf{P}_c(X_1=i)=\sum^{c}_{i=0}\textbf{P}_{c-i+1}(\tau=k)\textbf{P}_c(X_1=i)\\&=\sum^{c}_{i=0}\textbf{P}_{c-i+1}(\tau=k,Y_k=-j)\textbf{P}_c(X_1=i)(1-q)^{-j}/q\\&=\sum^{c}_{i=0}\textbf{P}_{c}(\tau=k+1,Y_{k+1}=-j|X_1=i)\textbf{P}_c(X_1=i)(1-q)^{-j}/q\\&=\textbf{P}_c(\tau=k+1,Y_{k+1}=-j)(1-q)^{-j}/q.\end{align*}

The first equation follows from the law of total probability, the second uses the fact that $(Y_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is a homogenous markov chain, the third  uses the induction hypothesis. From there we repeat all of theses steps in reverse.

Comment: Thank you very much. Consider the case $k \rightarrow k+1$. How do you exactly get to equation 2?

Comment: We know $X_1=i$, so c have to be c-i.

Comment: yes, but don't forget adding $k=1$ for the first step. If $(Y_n)$ was a random walk, you would be right, but strictly speaking it isn't: It's a random walk with increments.

Comment: Yes you are right. But why do I have to make sure, that I consider a homogenous markov chain, that equation holds.

Comment: Because if it was unhomogenous, the distribution might change from the second step onward. Basically we used the fact that $\textbf{P}(Y_{n+1}=k|Y_n=j)=\textbf{P}(Y_{n}=k|Y_{n-1}=j)$. The only equation I'm not a 100 percent sure about is the second last one.

Comment: How would you argue that $Y_{k+1}=-j$ at this equation?

Comment: If you consider the frist factor in third and second last equaion, you get: $$(c-i+1) +k - Y_k =-j \\ c + (k+1 )- Y_{k+1}=-j \Rightarrow c+ (k+1) -\sum_{i=2}^{k+1}X_i-i =-j$$

Comment: So you are wondering why $X_1=i$ ?

Comment: I don't know. It's just a feeling. You're probably right.

Comment: The probablities of this two equations would be the same assuming $X_1=i$, since $X_k$ are i.i.d and we have k summands.

Comment: But how do you justify that $X_1=i$

Comment: You don't justify it. You just say that the probabilites are the same, i.e. $\textbf{P}(\tau=k+1,Y_{k+1}=-j)=\textbf{P}(\tau=k,Y_{k}=-j|X_1=i)$. They probably are, but I am not sure whether it always holds or whether it follows from the memorylessnes of the geometric distribution.

Comment: Mhhh. I see. I tried to use memorylessnes of the geometric distribution in my question. Ignoring the fact that I did something wrong with independency, could I argue like that?

Comment: Do you have another idea?